# What is the meaning of this verse 2:2:10 of Krishna Yajurveda?

Tags: vedas, shiva, surya, yajur-veda, adityas

> Asavadityo na vy arocata tasmai devah, prayascittim aichan tasma etam.
>    Somaraudram carum nir avapan tenaivasmin rucam adadhus  (Krishna Yajurveda 2:2:10)

What is the exact meaning of this shloka?

Is it related to Surya & Rudra?

Answer (score 2):

[Krishna Yajurveda - 2:2:10](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/yv/yv02.htm)

> “asavadityo na vy arocata tasmai devah prayascittim aichan tasma etam
>   | somaraudram carum nir avapan tenaivasmin rucam adadhus |”
>
> “Yonder sun did not shine, the gods sought an atonement for him, for
>   him they offered this oblation to Soma and Rudra: verily thereby they
>   bestowed brightness upon him. If he desires to become resplendent, he
>   should offer for him this oblation to Soma and Rudra; verily he has
>   recourse to Soma and Rudra with their own portion; verily they bestow
>   upon him splendour; he becomes resplendent”.

The [Shaivism interpretation](http://indiafacts.org/glory-of-lord-kameshwara-vi-kama-sukta/) of the mantra is as follows;

> The Aditya who is the sun actually shines under the grace of Lord
>   Rudra as mentioned in Yajurveda. Rudra himself is present as sun as
>   well as moon also. But once Sun didn’t shine, all the gods prayed to
>   Soma-Rudra (the doctor aspect of Rudra, which in later texts called as
>   vaidyanatha), and he gave brightness to him. Soma (aspect) is Amruta
>   hence he gives life to any dying person. Hence he is the healer. But
>   it is lord Rudra who is the supreme light which illuminates
>   everything. Hence the Sun started shining again when Rudra imparted
>   brightness to him.
>
> Rudra alone is the supreme effulgent Atman whose light illuminates
>   everything.

---

If we ponder esoterically/SPIRITUALLY, we may get different perception.

In Rig Veda Rudra/Indra/Savitr/Varuna, etc are mentioned as one and the same BRAHMAN.

According to Advaita, everyone has God residing within oneself.  The Jnani knows it, others do not.  That is the difference.

This ignorance is termed as **realisation hidden in darkness** (waters capturing by Vritra) by Rig Veda.

Once ignorance is lifted, the **Realisation shines** by itself.

In the mantra in question, the hidden realisation was compared to lost brightness of Aditya.  And, due to the grace of BRAHMAN (Rudra), one's ignorance (darkness) will be removed, making the one REALISED.

Here,  Soma indicates bliss emanated out of realisation.